# Transform finite loop gif into infite loop

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04

I have a GIF animation `anim.gif` that lasts 4s.

I would like to transform this GIF to loop continuously.

How can I do this?

Comment: In just about *any* gif app.

Comment: anyone in particular that works on `Ubuntu 22.04`? What code can I use?

Answer (score 0):

See the post
[Animated gif only loops once in Chrome and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867789/animated-gif-only-loops-once-in-chrome-and-firefox)
for suggestions.

Some are :

[**gifsicle command line tool**](https://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/) :

`$ gifsicle --loopcount problem.gif > fixed.gif`

**ImageMagick**:

```
convert -loop 0 bad.gif good.gif
```

**Gimp**

Use `File > Export As` with "As Animation" and "Loop Forever".

**ffmpeg**

```
ffmpeg -i input.gif -loop 0 output.gif
```